# Azure Pipelines - Deployment Environment - Querying (+ deleting) Resources

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

Within the "Classic" deployment pipelines in Azure Devops we would utilise Azure Deployment Agents Groups to spin up a docker instance and then do things inside the container.

We are moving to YAML pipelines and are struggling to execute the same workflow.

It seems that there isn't feature parity so we need to utilise **Environments** within DevOps. I have a docker container that can register itself as a resource within a Environment with no issue. I can also use the REST API to query and create these on the fly.

My issue is that it doesn't seem to be possible to **delete** a resource without nuking the entire environment? We can query then via `/_apis/distributedtask/environments/62?expands=resourceReferences`

We can of course **unregister the resource** by running the remove command on the container, but then doesn't cater for the scenario of "what if the docker container dies/goes offline". We would be left with dangling resources which would block the creation of new ones

I originally got around this by creating a new dynamically named environment per container, but it seems that due to YAML evaluating the deployment environments ahead of running, this would not be viable (as the env wouldn't exist!)

So back to the actual question: Is it possible to delete/unregister a resource within an environment?

Comment: Additional:
I did try to work out what the `./config.cmd remove` command did to see if i could replicate but it seemingly just calls the Agent.Listener.exe rather than additional scripts.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to delete/unregister a resource in environment and keep the existing execution history at the same time?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT delete the resource from an environment, the history isn't important. For context I am basically just wanting to use these like deployment agents for tests, so spin up, execute, and spin down.
Due to not being able to delete, I just get `Environment with id 'N' already contains a virtual machine resource with name xxxx` as the resource is already registered.
An alternative is to randomise the name but then that list will grow

Comment: I have added an answer to share the steps to delete the resource from the environment. You can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to delete/unregister a resource within an environment?

Yes. We can use the following two methods to delete the VM resource in the Pipeline Environment.

Method1: We can manually delete the VM resource via **Delete Option** in Environment.

Check the screenshot sample

[image]

Method2: We can use the API to achieve it. We currently do not have an official Rest API to support this operation, but we can use the API captured by the backend(Browser F12 Option and check Network tab) to delete the Resource in the Environment.

Here is the API Example:

API url:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "contributionIds":["ms.vss-environments-web.environment-delete-resource-data-provider"],
    "dataProviderContext":
      {
          "properties":
          {
              "resourceId":"{VMresourceID}",
              "resourceType":"2",
              "sourcePage":
                 {
                     "url":"https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_environments/{environmentID}?view=resources",
                     "routeId":"ms.vss-environments-web.environments-route-with-id",
                     "routeValues":{
                          "project":"{Projectname}",
                          "environmentId":"{environmentID}",
                          "viewname":"environment",
                          "controller":"ContributedPage",
                          "action":"Execute"
                      }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

We can get the related parameters with the Rest API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/environments/{environmentId}?expands=resourceReferences&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Comment: That works amazingly. Thank you for the recommendation, I managed to validate this through the devtools and then matched against the post great. Do you happen to know what permission this utilises for the PAT? I have a "god mode" PAT for everythign but we tend to use more focussed ones in production.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper Since it is not an official API, there is no exact scope to implement it. Based on my tests, full access(God mode) PAT is currently required.